# How to add Project Creation Window to Swing JMenuItem

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jdialog

I have JMenuItems , I wanna add to Project Creation dialog to JMenuItem (New) similar to any other Application  , I am confused with that a little bit. Is it going to be JDialog , JFrame or JPanel to create such window shown in picture. Maybe I can also add click next in the future as well.

Maybe Similar to

[image]

Regards

Comment: I don't see how `JPanel` is even in the running. You're pretty safe sticking to a modal `JDialog`

Comment: You have to use a Swing top-level container: JFrame or JDialog. You can add a JMenuBar to both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that standard container for JmenuItems is Jmenubar so add the Jmenuitems to Jmenubar then add Jmenubar to any other container (JPanel, JDialog , JFrame)
Hope that helps[Menu Tutorial http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html)

Comment: Sorry Man , It doesn't help :)) I have already JMenuBar  , I need to create dialog which interracts with user to create new project for example !

Comment: Do you mean dynamic menu items creation ?

Comment: imagine like eclipse you go to new and create project